# SELECT pii2 FROM `encuestas_egresados` WHERE pii2='Muy buena' BETWEEN fecha ='2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-01' ;

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un error de sintaxis en la siguiente sentencia

```
SELECT pii2 
FROM `encuestas_egresados`
WHERE pii2='Muy buena'
BETWEEN fecha ='2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-01' ;
```

Comment: Ingresa el error que te marca

Answer (score 2):

La condición siguiente no es correcta:

```
BETWEEN fecha ='2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
```

Debería ser:

```
AND fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
```

..aunque, en este caso en particular, como ambas fechas son iguales, ni siquiera necesitas usar el `BETWEEN`:

```
AND fecha = '2017-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería:

```
SELECT pii2 
FROM `encuestas_egresados`
WHERE pii2='Muy buena'
AND fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-01' ;
```

Comment: Si explicaras tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor, lee [answer], saludos!